# Adding and Removing Xmlnode using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, xml-parsing, powershell-2.0

I am trying to add and remove elements from multiple xml files. i ran into two issue. it removed empty elements automatically and second it did not remove what i wanted to

I have my xml like this

```
<Entity>
   <App>
      <item1>1</item1>
      <emptyItem/>
      <person>
         <itemToRemove>true</itemToRemove>
         <emptyItem/>
         <otheritem>1</otheritem>
      </person>
      <person>
         <itemToRemove>false</itemToRemove>
         <emptyItem/>
         <otheritem>3</otheritem>
      </person>
      <person>
         <itemToRemove>false</itemToRemove>
         <emptyItem/>
         <otheritem>3</otheritem>
      </person>
   </App>
</Entity>
```

what i want is

```
<Entity>
   <App>
      <item1>1</item1>
      <emptyItem/>
      <person>

         <emptyItem/>
         <otheritem>1</otheritem>
      </person>
      <person>

         <emptyItem/>
         <otheritem>3</otheritem>
      </person>
      <person>

         <emptyItem/>
         <otheritem>3</otheritem>
      </person>
      <newItemtoAdd>2001-01-01</newItemtoAdd>
   </App>
</Entity>
```

**i added newItemtoAdd element and removed itemToRemove on output xml above.**

```
with the current script i have used what i get is this

<Entity>
   <App>
      <item1>1</item1>
      <emptyItem/>
      <person>
         <itemToRemove>true</itemToRemove>
         <otheritem>1</otheritem>
      </person>
      <person>
         <itemToRemove>false</itemToRemove>
         <otheritem>3</otheritem>
      </person>
      <person>
         <itemToRemove>false</itemToRemove>
         <otheritem>3</otheritem>
      </person>
      <newItemtoAdd>2001-01-01</newItemtoAdd>
   </App>
</Entity>
```

**emptyItem node is removed which i do not want to happen, newItemtoAdd is added which is good, and itemToRemove node is not removed which is not what i want**

here is my script

```
Get-ChildItem D:\Projects\*.xml | 
    % { 
        [xml]$xml      = [xml](Get-Content $_.fullname)
        $newItemtoAdd = $xml.CreateElement('newItemtoAdd')
        $newItemtoAdd.PsBase.InnerText = '1900-01-01'
        $null     = $xml.Entity.App.AppendChild($newItemtoAdd)

    $xml.SelectNodes("//Entity/App/person") | ? {
    $_.name -eq "itemToRemove"   } | % {$_.ParentNode.RemoveChildNode($_) }
       $xml.Save($_.FullName)
    }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem D:\Projects\*.xml | % {
    [Xml]$xml = Get-Content $_.FullName

    $newItemtoAdd = $xml.CreateElement('newItemtoAdd')
    $newItemtoAdd.PsBase.InnerText = '1900-01-01'
    $xml.Entity.App.AppendChild($newItemtoAdd) | Out-Null

    $parent_xpath = '/Entity/App/person'
    $nodes = $xml.SelectNodes($parent_xpath)
    $nodes | % {
        $child_node = $_.SelectSingleNode('itemToRemove')
        $_.RemoveChild($child_node) | Out-Null
    }

    $xml.OuterXml | Out-File $_.FullName
}
```

Comment: When i am using some code to itterate the nodes and don't know the path

Comment: I know this is old, but this script removes all my whitespace/linebreaks. Thoughts?

Comment: @theB3RV - try [the `Save` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.save) of XML document. It may behave differently. (instead of the `Out-File` cmdlet)

Answer (score 6):

To remove a node from all xml-files in a directory, and save result as a new xml-file, I use this powershell-script:

```
Get-ChildItem .\*.xml | % {
    [Xml]$xml = Get-Content $_.FullName
    $xml | Select-Xml -XPath '//*[local-name() = ''itemToRemove'']' | ForEach-Object{$_.Node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_.Node)}
    $xml.OuterXml | Out-File .\result.xml -encoding "UTF8"
}
```

Note: the "local-name"-syntax is for ignoring namespaces.

Comment: I believe that this will remove the children of 'itemToRemove', not that node. To remove that node, change to "$_.Node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_.Node) . Otherwise, looks good, thanks for the example.

Comment: What does the % mean between the pipe and the leading bracket here?

Comment: @Sly_Boots It is short for `ForEach`, looping through all matched files.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell has two nice syntax features which might be used in this case:

#### 1. `Xml` dot notation

Where you might directly reference a node in your `xml` file.
For example, to select the `itemToRemove` for the first (`0` based) `Person`:

```
$Xml.Entity.App.person[0].itemToRemove
true
```

Unfortunately this PowerShell feature is a little overdone as you can see from the example where instead of returning an [`XmlElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlelement?view=net-6.0), it returns a `string` with the `innerText` (`#Text`) if it concerns a leaf note, see: [`#16878` Decorate dot selected Xml strings (leaves) with XmlElement methods](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16878).

#### 2. [Member-Access Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration)

> You can use member enumeration to get property values from all members of a collection. When you use the member access operator (`.`) with a member name on a collection object, such as an array, if the collection object does not have a member of that name, the items of the collection are enumerated and PowerShell looks for that member on each item. This applies to both property and method members.

Taking the `xml` file in the question as an example:

```
$Xml.Entity.App.person.itemToRemove
true
false
false
```

Note that in this example, there is no index behind the `Person` property, meaning that *all* persons are enumerated and returned.
To overcome a possible returned `string` (described in **1. `xml` dot notation**) you might enumerate the [`SelectNodes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes?view=net-6.0) on each `person` node instead and use that to removed the concerned nodes from their parent:

```
$Xml.Entity.App.person.SelectNodes('itemToRemove').ForEach{ $Null = $_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_) }
[System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Parse($Xml.OuterXml).ToString()
```

```
<Entity>
  <App>
    <item1>1</item1>
    <emptyItem />
    <person>
      <emptyItem />
      <otheritem>1</otheritem>
    </person>
    <person>
      <emptyItem />
      <otheritem>3</otheritem>
    </person>
    <person>
      <emptyItem />
      <otheritem>3</otheritem>
    </person>
  </App>
</Entity>
```