# Powershell remove XML tags

Tags: xml, powershell

I’m new to PowerShell and am trying to remove a XML element from a xml XML file of mine.

To do this I have used the following example code that got from [Adding and Removing Xmlnode using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939930/adding-and-removing-xmlnode-using-powershell)

The example works well but when I try to adept it for my code it no longer works. The code is as follows:

```bsh
$Output = "C:\Users\Desktop\resulttest.xml"
# Load the existing document
$Doc = [xml](Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Desktop\test.xml)

# Specify tag names to delete and then find them
$DeleteNames= "body"
($Doc.Task.ChildNodes | Where-Object { $DeleteNames -contains $_.Name }) | ForEach-Object {
    # Remove each node from its parent
    [void]$_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_)
}
# Save the modified document
$Doc.Save($Output)
```

I use the following example XML file:

```xml
<html>a
<body>b</body>
<Price>300</Price>
<Total> 5000 </Total>
 <Part_C>
 <Name>Jar</Name>
<Title>Mr</Title>
<CountryCode> 5000 </CountryCode>
</Part_C>
</html>
```

The goal of the XML file is that it removes multiple tags like "Price" and "Total" or "Price", "Title", "Total"

But when I run the code it still contains these tags .

My question is what I am doing wrong and how can I ensure that PowerShell removes the XML tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without going too deep into it, I think the problem may be that you're not operating on the `$Doc` element itself. I'd use XML methods `SelectNodes` directly on it:

```
$Doc.ChildNodes.SelectNodes($DeleteNames) | Foreach-Object {
    $Doc.ChildNodes.RemoveChild($_)
}
$Doc.Save($Output)
```

**UPDATE:**
If `$DeleteNames` contain more than one criteria/node, one would need to make it an array and call the code once for each (SelectNodes does not support patterns):

```
,"Price","Total" | Foreach-Object { 
    $Doc.ChildNodes.SelectNodes($_) | Foreach-Object {
...
```

I suppose you could do an alternate node selection using e.g. XPath, but I haven't dug much into that.

Comment: The new code works greath but i have another problem with it now. The problem is that when i try the remove two tages like <Price> and <Total>  or <Price> and <Title> it does not work.

Comment: For that to work using my code above, you need to make `$DeleteNames` an array and call it accordingly. Added that now.

Comment: I have tried changing the code but get now the following  error:  ** "Method invocation failed because [System.Xml.XmlElement] does not contain a method named 'SelectNode'.
At C:\Users\EX27740\Desktop\Eric 3 verwijderen meerdere rijen.ps1:9 char:5"**  i Am using the following code:


**$Doc = [xml](Get-Content -Path C:\Users\EX27740\Desktop\TestEric.xml)

# Specify tag names to delete
$DeleteNames = ,"body","Price","Total" | Foreach-Object { 
    $Doc.ChildNodes.SelectNode($_)} | Foreach-Object {

    $Doc.ChildNodes.RemoveChild($DeleteNames)
}
$Doc.Save($Output) **

Comment: Sorry, `SelectNode` above should have been `SelectNodes`. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

This works perfectly.

```
$Output = "resulttest.xml"
$Doc = [xml]"<task><body>b</body><bla>bla</bla></task>"

$DeleteNames = "body"

$Doc.Task.ChildNodes | Where-Object { $DeleteNames -eq $_.Name } | ForEach-Object {
    $_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_) | Out-Null
}

$Doc.Save($Output)
```

My guess would be that `$Doc.Task` does not actually select anything in your XML document.