# Finding and deleted items from XML in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I was hoping some one can help me with how to manage xml data in powershell. I have worked out how to import it but I am having some trouble understanding how to malipulate it.

What i want to do is loop though xml exported from a DHCP server, and when it gets to the scope section look at each of the "optionvalue" and remove each one that does not have an "optionID" of 3. In the example below I want to remove the entire chunk highlighted yellow based on "optionID != 3"

I can find this in the xml but i cant work out how to remove it all cleanly and efficently.

I worked out you can use this code, but it only finds the first instance of a node where "OptionID != 3" is there a way to make it find all instance or would you do it by using a loop to keep checking untill there are no more to find.

```
$nodeToRemove = $dhcpdate.SelectSingleNode("//OptionId[text()!='3']")
$level1Parent = $nodeToRemove.ParentNode.ParentNode
$level1Parent.RemoveChild($nodeToRemove.ParentNode)
```

Thank you

[image: XML]

Comment: See: [Adding and Removing Xmlnode using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23973074/1701026). Please add a (sanitized) text based ([no images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1701026) but a [mcve]) to your question if you are looking for an answer on your specific `xml` file.

Comment: Instead of ```SelectSingleNode``` which by definition "selects the first XmlNode that matches the XPath expression." (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectsinglenode?view=net-7.0) try ```SelectNodes``` which "selects a list of nodes matching the XPath expression." (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes?view=net-7.0) and then use a ```foreach``` to iterate over the results and remove each one in turn...

Answer (score 1):

Try Xml Linq with PS

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$inputFilename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$outputFilename = "c:\temp\test1.xml"

$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)
$ns = $doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace()

$optionValues = $doc.Descendants($ns + "OptionValues")
$id3 = [pscustomobject]@([System.Linq.Enumerable]::Where($optionValues.Elements($ns + 'OptionValue'), [Func[object,bool]]{ param($x) [string]$x.Elements($ns + 'OptionId').Value -eq "3"}))

$optionValues.RemoveNodes()
$optionValues.Add($id3)

$doc.Save($outputFilename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the sugestions, with thoese in mind I pieced togather this code, I am sure that i could have made it a little cleaner but for what i need it works :)

This is prety much what Mcayton sugested in their comment above.

```
while ($sourcedata.SelectSingleNode("//Scope/OptionValues/OptionValue/OptionId[text()!='3']"))
 {
    $nodeToRemove = $sourcedata.SelectSingleNode("//Scope/OptionValues/OptionValue/OptionId[text()!='3']")
    $level1Parent = $nodeToRemove.ParentNode.ParentNode
    $level1Parent.RemoveChild($nodeToRemove.ParentNode)
}
```